# Running multiple jobs for pipeline on Azure DevOps Self-Hosted Agent

Tags: azure, azure-devops, pipeline, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

I encountered an error which I was fighting for a few days already, without success. I have a multistage pipeline written for Azure DevOps and Self-Hosted agent, is it possible to run multiple concurrent runs, for different branches on a different workspace?

I mean, I have queued runs for: dev, dev2, master, etc., and I wanna run three concurrent runs in separate workspaces for them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install multiple instances of the agent on your build agent. One agent only runs 1 job at a time. But you can just install as many copies of the agent on the same server as you want, just extract the agent to a new folder and register it.

Comment: Okay, but in this case, how to execute the whole pipeline run on one Agent? I have a multistage pipeline, one stage needs built code from another, and I'm not using artifacts. I just set `checkout: none` in jobs.

Comment: That isn't how Azure Pipelines works.  If you're using jobs and stages you should really be using artifacts.

Comment: If you always run the jobs on the same server, you could fiddle around with the agent demands and use something like the agents hostname https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/demands?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml,  but each agent will have its own working directory and each job will be executed in a subfolder underneath that. So you won't end up in the same work folder with the build output in it.

Comment: but it will use a lot of space, even if I'll be using `artifacts Type: file path`. I basically need just code from the very last stage, and I need to store it on file share.

Comment: Yes. That's true, but it it what it is.